# How do i simplify $\cos(4x)\cos(3x)−4\sin(x)\sin(3x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How do i simplify $\cos(4x)\cos(3x) − 4\sin(x)\sin(3x)\cos(x)\cos(2x)$ ?

I tried plugging in the double angle formulas $\cos(x+3x)$ and $\cos(x+2x)$ and went nowhere please help me.

Also maybe
$\cos^{-1}(t) - \sin^{-1}(t)$ for $t$ in $(-1,1)$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We play for a while with the second term $4\sin x\cos x\cos(2x)\sin(3x)$. Note that $2\sin x\cos x=\sin(2x)$. Using similar reasoning, we conclude  therefore that $4\sin x\cos x\cos(2x)=2\sin(2x)\cos(2x)=\sin(4x)$.

So our expression is equal to
$$\cos(4x)\cos(3x)-\sin(4x)\sin(3x).$$
By the addition law for cosine, this is $\cos(7x)$.

Comment: You are welcome. I see your comment got interrupted. That happens when one presses the Return key. Used to happen to me a lot.

Comment: In, cos(4x)cos(3x)−4sin(x)sin(3x)cos(x)cos(2x)

arrange as, =cos(4x)cos(3x)-2sin(x)cos(x)*2sin(3x)cos(2x) 
see that, 2sinxcosx=sin(2x) 
so, =cos(4x)cos(3x)-sin(2x)*2sin(3x)cos(2x)  eq(a)

But, 2sin(2x)cos(2x)=sin(4x)

And eq(a) arrange as = cos(4x)cos(3x)-2sin(2x)cos(2x)*sin(3x) 

Hence, = cos(4x)cos(3x)-2sin(4x)sin(3x) 

Which is the sum angle of cos(4x+3x) = cos(7x) 

Tytytytytytytytytytyyt

Comment: At the very end you have a typo. You wrote $\cos(4x)\cos(3x)-2\sin(4x)\sin(3x)$. There should not be a $2$ there, please see my answer. Both $2$'s from the $4$ get absorbed, in going from $4\sin x\cos x\cos(2x)$ to $\sin(4x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a systematic procedure: Put $e^{ix}=:z$ and use Euler's formula to rewrite the given expression in terms of $z$. E.g., $\cos(4x)=(z^4+z^{-4})/2$. When an essential simplification is possible this will be reflected in the resulting rational function of $z$. In the case at hand the result is
$${1+z^{14}\over 2z^7}\ .$$